# Heroku not automatically deploying changes

Tags: github, heroku, deployment

I'm having an issue where I can only deploy changes to heroku via a manual command.

I've already followed the guide and set up auto deployment through github https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration but it seems like changes are not deployed to heroku unless I explicitly run `git push heroku main`

Is there anything I can do to check how to automate the push?

Answer (score 1):

Automatic deploy with Heroku and Github is temporary stopped

https://dev.to/lukeecart/herokus-github-integration-has-been-stopped-a7c

Follow the news : https://status.heroku.com/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).